# Equation of graph from the graph

Tags: graph

How would I go about finding the equation of the solid black line exponential/logarithm graph?

The two data points are:

(x,y)

(9,-14)

(20,-21)

[image]

Comment: You could try DataThief... see https://datathief.org/

Comment: First you should decide what kind of function you want as an answer. Do you want a polynomial? Or maybe \$ae^{-bx}\$? Maybe some other function.

Comment: @SolarMike looks promising will give it a go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics

Comment: If it wasn't for solarMike I wouldn't have been able to solve this. So maybe before a question gets closed maybe give it a day till it's closed. Just like SolarMike you never know someone might just be able to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grabbing information from datasheets and producing useful coefficients, I've successfully used [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/).

[Here](http://connectedresearchers.com/graph-digitizer-comparison-16-ways-to-digitize-your-data/) is a comparison of various programs, apparently the reservations expressed for WebPlotDigitizer have been dealt with and no longer apply, but do your DD.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to find the equation for an exponential first take the log and you'll get something that should look like a line, then fit the log result to a line.

You'll get two parameters

y = m*x+b

then to find the fit, take the exponential of the original line:

Y = exp(m*x+b)